# Detecting whether a mouse button is down in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I don't want to use the mouseup event because I want to allow the user to drag outside the control. I need to check the state via a timer. I vaguely remember doing this before at some point by using

```
If MouseButtons = MouseButtons.Left Then...
```

But now it says that MouseButtons is a type and cannot be used as an expression (which is true, its an enum type).

Maybe they changed things or maybe I just remember wrong.. either way, how would I check if the button is still down?

Comment: `MouseButtons` is a shared property of the `Form` class. Use the fully qualified namespace `If (MouseButtons = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then`

Comment: that yields the same answer by intellisense

Comment: Then change the LHS to `System.Windows.Forms.Form.MouseButtons`.

Comment: Then close&reopen vs > clear > rebuild.

Comment: the MouseButtons property is a member of the main form and I'm writing a class outside of it

Comment: Again: The MouseButtons is a **shared** property of the Form class. This error should not occur if you a) use fully qualified namespaces 2) Have a reference to system.windows.forms.dll. You need to revisit the help center. Focus on the MCVE section: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Again, i tried that and it doesn't work. Try it yourself

Comment: I did, and it worked. You need to add an image, show the stacktrace, exact error message, compiler/application config/info. VS 5/8/10/12? :net 1/2/3.5/4/4.5?

Comment: @Bjorn It doesnt work outside in a new class, I can assure that. Yeah it may be a shared property but not for his case. Hes talking about another class in general. I want to see you put the code you said worked in a new class and try and compile and run it. Not a form class either...

Comment: @436f6465786572 Oh really? I've uploaded a sample app to github for you novice's to play with: https://github.com/kringsjaa/MouseMagic

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå that's a lot of work for something very easy. In your program class, your using another class: Window that inherit's FORM, this is not correct. If you read above in my comment I specifically said: `Not a form class either` which mean's not inherit the Form class. Also if you create a new project and try to get the `MouseButton` that is held down `from another class` the way you suggested does not work period. Is that why you created a class that inherits `Form`?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå also `MouseButtons` is an enumeration, which button is held down, how do you know which one? From what I see all you do is have a private variable declared as `MouseButtons` and all you do is set it if it's not equal, this doesn't do anything beside's set the variable and invalidate... Could you clarify my finding's so I can better understand what I am missing?

Comment: @436f6465786572 How do you plan to run a winforms app without a window? And as you can see, I'm calling MouseButtons from *another* class. If you read my previous comments you'll see that OP keeps saying that it fails with *" is a type and cannot be used as an expression"* which is nonsense. Also, AFAIK OP have *not* mentioned that the class reside in *another assembly*. I'm trying to make a point here: This question is unclear and lacks vital information.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I agree I am taking it one way than the way you took the approach. Anyways thank's for clarification!

Comment: @436f6465786572 MouseButtons is a *flag* enumeration. Use the bitwise operator to check if the value contains a give flag. `Dim leftIsDown = ((buttons And Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tried and tested. I created a new class: testmouseclass and created a shared function you can use anytime to determine if the `LeftMouseButton` is down. This is possible with the help of `GetAsyncKeyState` call.

```
 Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 'Need to import...

 Public Class testmouseclass

 <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling:=True)> Public Shared Function GetAsyncKeyState(ByVal vkey As Long) As Long
End Function

Public Shared Function LeftMouseIsDown() As Boolean
    Return GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) > 0 And &H8000
End Function

 End Class
```

**Example Usage**

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If testmouseclass.LeftMouseIsDown() Then MsgBox("It IS!")
   End Sub
```

Depending on the timer tick's this can be a headache as well. Not sure how you are using this, but in my example I had the timer at 3 seconds and when I held the `LeftMouseButton` down a message popped up and when I clicked it again it popped up again because of the timer and the left mouse was down. Also this work's even outside of your application...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to test the [Mouse.LeftButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.leftbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Comment: There is no Mouse class available. I'm writing this from a class other than the main form.

Comment: @user81993 You may need to `Import System.Windows.Input` (at the very top of your file).

Comment: the only thing available to me in system.windows.input is an interface called ICommand

Comment: What type of project are you building (WinForms, WPF, console, etc..)?

Comment: just the regular kind of winforms exe in .net 4.5

Comment: Hmm, until I can sit down at my desk and experiment, you've got me stumped. It's probably something very simple, but in the mean-time, what happens when you try [Bjorn's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715493/detecting-whether-a-mouse-button-is-down-in-vb-net/30715562?noredirect=1#comment49488835_30715493)?

Answer (score 0):

```
If System.Windows.Input.Mouse.LeftButton = Windows.Input.MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
```

Comment: Please read the [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) due to too less information.