# C# how to toggle simulated mouse clicks with left mouse button

Tags: c#

I would like to so when I hold my left mouse button down it simulates clicks but this is not working as it's not simulating clicks but if I remove the if statement in the `timer1`, it simulates clicks but I want it to only simulate when I'm holding left mouse.

Here is my code so far what I've done. if you could help that would be great

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
    //Mouse actions
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;




    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.Left){
            DoMouseClick();
        }
    }

    public void DoMouseClick()
    {
        //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
        uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
        uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.. have a look at this answer.. it may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715493/detecting-whether-a-mouse-button-is-down-in-vb-net

Comment: @Wheels73 is that not for vb tho?

Comment: It is... the principle still stands though.. its only syntax!

Comment: so how would i be able to do that in c#?

Comment: The .net framework is the same across the 2 languages. Where they've gone private Sub, c# says private void... replace End with { } brackets. etc..